# Java Android GCM getting collapse_key

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I just read that it is possible to group some messages to a collapse_key. Is it possible to get this collapse_key in the IntentService? I would need it for identification reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean with an Intent? Try this:

```
String collapseKey = intent.getStringExtra("collapse_key");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this in your IntentService:

```
intent.getExtras().getString("collapse_key");
```